# Suitable use of BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am about to use a BlockingCollection like below and just wanted to check that it was suitable for thread safety etc.  Was wondering if I needed a CancellationTokenSource for anything.

Thanks

```
public class MyApp
{
  private BlockingCollection<int> blockingCollection;

  public void Start()
  {
     blockingCollection= new BlockingCollection<int>();
     var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessData);
  }

  public void Add(int value)
  {
    blockingCollection.Add(value); //This is a thread that receives input
  }

  private void ProcessData()
  {
    foreach(var item in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {  
      ...
    }
  }

  public void Finish()
  {
    blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
  }
}
```

Comment: You might want to specify [`LongRunning` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx) when creating the `Task`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you may use cancellation token to support graceful cancellation pattern in your code:

```
  private readonly CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

  public void Start()
  {
     blockingCollection= new BlockingCollection<int>();
     var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessData, cts.Token);
  }

  private void ProcessData()
  {
    foreach(var item in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable(cts.Token))
    {  
        cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // ...
    }
  }

  public void Cancel()
  {
      cts.Cancel();
  }
```

Comment: When would a caller call `Cancel()` instead of `Finish()`?  I don't understand the difference between a cancellation and what the OP does with the call to `CompleteAdding()`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `BlockingCollection` itself is thread-safe. From MSDN:

> IProducerConsumerCollection represents a collection that allows
>   for thread-safe adding and removing of data. BlockingCollection is
>   used as a wrapper for an IProducerConsumerCollection instance,
>   allowing removal attempts from the collection to block until data is
>   available to be removed.

Ok, this doesn't say much about the actual code using it, but from what I see in your code it's used correctly.